# How to enable hibernation in panel on Luna?

Tags: wingpanel, luna

I followed the steps in https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

I can hibernate from the command line, but there’s still no entry in the power menu for hibernation.

Comment: The Question is about a release or feature that has been significantly updated, to the point at which upgrading fixes the issue or answers the question.